# Authorised.net not working for magento2

Tags: magento2

Below error it will be showed on
"Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller."
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/1002744/hzvm02m0rtkfvncdgv0c

Answer (score 0):

Pleae change sandbox URL:

Sandbox URLs:
https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll - gateway
https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api - transaction details

Production URLs:
https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll - gateway
https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api - transaction details